# How to target all elements with a specific class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working with WordPress and Bootstrap 5.

Due to WordPress limitations with the `wp_nav_men` function. I can't see the markup at all. This means I can't manually added classes here and there. I need to do this in order to get the Bootstrap sub menu navs to work. This means I need to use JavaScript to inject specific things to certain elements to

For me to achieve this, it would seem I need to get additional child nodes with the same class names to inherit the same JavaScript settings. Here's what I am trying to do. Below I have listed what I see in the markup, the steps I would like to see happen, and what the JavaScript looks like currently.

**MARKUP:**

```
<ul id="mainNav" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item-has-children  highlight"><a href="" id="dropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle show" aria-expanded="true"></a>
        
        <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu show" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(906px, 61px, 0px);" data-popper-placement="bottom-start">
            <li id="menu-item-269" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href=""></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-271" class=""><a href=""></a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-272" class=""><a href=""></a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-270" class=""><a href=""></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-101" class=""><a href="">Product</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="">About Us</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-228" class=""><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-105" class=""><a href="">News and Events</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-106" class=""><a href="">Join Our Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-99" class=""><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**STEP 1:**
If any `li` with a class of `.menu-item-has-children`, add the following `id`, `role`, `data-bs-toggle` and `class` to the element.

**STEP 2:**
Any `li` with a with a class of `.menu-item-has-children` also with a `ul` will have a sub nav menu. Because of this, the sub nav menu must inherit the following `class` of `dropdown-menu`.

```
    // Toggle child menu item in main nav

    // assign expanse li to variable
    let liExpanse = document.querySelector('.menu-item-has-children');

    // check if nested ul is contained in parent li of main nav
    let liExpanseChild = document.querySelector('.sub-menu');

    // add id, role, data attributes to div
    function addAtt() {
        liExpanse.firstChild.setAttribute('id','dropdownMenuLink');
        liExpanse.firstChild.setAttribute('role','button');
        liExpanse.firstChild.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle','dropdown');
    }
    addAtt();

    // add classnames to divs
    function addClassName() {
        liExpanse.firstChild.classList.add('nav-link', 'dropdown-toggle');
        liExpanseChild.classList.add('dropdown-menu');
    }
    addClassName();
```

**THOUGHTS:**
I do notice that when using `firstChild` methods, it only looks for the first child. There is also a `lastChild` option, but what I am looking for is to find all nodes with a class of `.menu-item-has-children`, then do the following.

With some research and based on comments, I actually don't want the querySelectorAll to pick up on *all* that is related to that class or ID. Just the one level.

Comment: If you're looking to find *all nodes* instead of *the first node* then you should use querySelectorAll instead of querySelector.  Note that querySelectorAll returns a list and not a single element, so you will have to loop through it.

Comment: Can you explain to me further about what you mean by "returns a list and not a single element"?

Comment: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns all elements that match the selector, in a list.

Comment: Hi there, so I gave `document.querySelectorAll` a try and it literally finds everything with that class name, not just one one level but multiple levels down. How do you search for only one level?

Comment: It seems that you want to do Step 1 to `document.querySelectorAll("li.menu-item-has-children > a")` (all `<a>` elements that are direct children of li elements with menu-item-has-children class)  And Step 2 to `document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu")` (all elements with class sub-menu.  Yes it will search all the way down the levels.  If that's not what you want perhaps you can clarify your question, it doesn't mention levels.

Comment: @James, sorry I should have been more clear. I actually didn't know that querySelectorAll would do that.

Comment: @jameslau `querySelectorAll` is the way to go. You just need to write a [CSS SELECTOR](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) specific enough so it only matches the elements you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top-level elements will have `.menu` as their parent.  You could also use `#mainNav` in its place.  In css `>` means thing on the left is a direct parent of thing on the right.

Top-level anchor selector

```
document.querySelectorAll(".menu > .menu-item-has-children > a")
```

Top-level submenu selector

```
document.querySelectorAll(".menu > .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu")
```

Using the id of the parent instead of the class, if its more convenient

```
document.querySelectorAll("#mainNav > .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu")
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. You actually have to be specific about how far it goes. That makes a sense.